# Crm2013/15 Online and queries on huge data volumes

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm working on a couple of million records, as soon as I try to run an advanced find, and put as a criteria a linked entity, the advanced find goes in timeout.

Create custom views on this allows me to filter properly? Anyone knows the proper way of using the advanced find this way? Are there limitations on the out of the box CRM that i should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was too early to post an answer. The problem that I encountered was related to the OOB advanced find. Looking for example for an account with some related contacts (a really plain search with a linked entity) i had a SQL timeout. Everything was OOB so I was a little bit clueless and I opened a case to Microsoft. They found a bug, if i was changing the sorting the advanced find started to work again. They are still investigating. So wasn't a setting problem but a crm bug.

Answer (score 0):

In CRM 2013 - it is possible to add indexes for specific fields by adding the columns to the quick find view for the entity.

You will need to wait for the Indexing Management Job to run (which is run every 24 hours by default) - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/darrenliu/archive/2014/04/02/crm-2013-maintenance-jobs.aspx.

In previous version of CRM, it was necessary to add the indexes directly to the database - this may be necessary for more complex queries.

Comment: Hi Alan, we actually contacted microsoft and my case resulted in a bug on the advanced find (play around with the sorting options fixed it). I was aware of the quick search indexing (but in my case wasn't applicable since i was searching records based on a relationship for example: get me all the accounts that have at least 1 contact.

Comment: @Draiden Sounds like you have a reasonable fix for this.  Can you provide a more detailed answer (as an answer rather than comment) and mark as accepted?